# How can I remove the repeating characters in each columns?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have made a new data frame using 
df_all

```
         classA classB    year1 count1    docID1          year2   count2           doc2            
        0   A8   B1        1972    1       0               1973      3      U015|U348|U768     
        1   A8   B2        1972    2    U157|U596          1973      0             0            
        2   A8   B3        1972    0       0               1973      1      U124
```

and I have merged the docID1 and docID2 into the new column by

```
df_all['all_doc']=df_all['docID1'].astype(str)+'|'+df_all['docID2'].astype(str)

     classA classB    year1 count1    docID1          year2   count2           doc2            all_doc
    0   A8   B1        1972    1       0               1973      3      U015|U348|U768      ||U015|U348|U768
    1   A8   B2        1972    2    U157|U596          1973      0             0            U157|U596|0
    2   A8   B3        1972    0       0               1973      1      U124                ||U124
```

in the `'all_doc'` column, it has duplicate '|' in each row. I wonder how to remove duplicate '|' in every row

I expect to see the result in like this

```
|U015|U348|U768
|U124
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Share the input dataframe and the desired output dataframe, please. You are talking about a column I can't even see.

Comment: the current output does not correlate with mentioned columns. Post the actual data

Comment: And if your input df is gigantic, reduce it in the process of constructing a [MCVE].

Comment: I have updated the post, sorry for my mistakes

Comment: Looks strange: A column that contains number `0` becomes `"0"` after `<column>.astype(str)` but you have `||` instead

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([['foo', '||U015|U348|U768'], ['bar', 'U157|U596|0'], ['baz', '||U124']], columns=['fiz', 'all_doc'])
>>> df
   fiz           all_doc
0  foo  ||U015|U348|U768
1  bar       U157|U596|0
2  baz            ||U124
```

you can issue

```
>>> df['all_doc'] = df['all_doc'].str.replace('\|+', '|')
>>> df
   fiz          all_doc
0  foo  |U015|U348|U768
1  bar      U157|U596|0
2  baz            |U124
```

The regular expression `\|+` specifies a sequence of `|` characters. Each of these sequences is replaced by a single `|`.

Answer (score 0):

#### [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) + [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) + `sum`

You can filter for appropriate columns by label, replace `0` with empty strings, and then sum:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'docID1': [0, 'U157|U596', 0],
                   'doc2': ['U015|U348|U768', 0, 'U124']})

df['all_doc'] = '|' + df.filter(regex='^doc').replace(0, '').sum(1)

print(df)

      docID1            doc2          all_doc
0          0  U015|U348|U768  |U015|U348|U768
1  U157|U596               0       |U157|U596
2          0            U124            |U124
```